# Howto Step by Step in Debug Mode Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms

How can I step by step debug an android app in DDMS??

I only find the "Step into" and "Step over" ....

Thanks for help!

Bye!

Comment: step into -> F5
 step over F6

Comment: And what did you want to find? "Step into" allows you to debug a function which is being called, "Step over" just executes the function and jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well step over is the answer....it exactly does step by step debugging

Answer (score 0):

Step over allows you to go step by step, step into allows to get into the function and step return  allows you to get back where you stopped with step over